# Nested Reactive Expressions in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to create a simple app with these features :

User will select "Custom" or "Default".

If "Default" is selected, a default text will be shown. But if "Custom" is selected, user will be able to "Submit" a text and that submitted text will be shown.

I have written some code to do this, but unable to handle the two reactive expressions simultaneously in the "Custom" case.

Here is the code :

```
library( shiny )

ui = navbarPage(

title = 'Text',

tabPanel(

'Custom App',

fluidRow(


  radioButtons( 'radio', 'Select Action', choices = list( 'Default' = 'Default', 'Custom' = 'Custom' ),

                selected = 'Default', inline = T ),

  column( 6, textInput( 'text_given', label = 'Enter Text', value = '' ) ),

  actionButton( 'submit_button', 'Submit' ),

  textOutput( text )

  )

)

)

server = function( input, output, session ){

main = reactive({

selected_action = input$radio

  if( selected_action == 'Default' ){

    text_to_show = 'Default Text'

  } else{

    dataInput = eventReactive( input$submit_button,{

      text_to_show = input$text_given

    })

 }

 return( list( 'text_output' = text_to_show ) )

})

output$text = renderText( main()$text_output )

}

shinyApp( ui = ui, server = server )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to nest your reactives. You should create your reactiveExpression outside of the reactive, and refer to that object from within your reactive. I believe this does what you want, let me know if this helps!

```
library( shiny )

ui = navbarPage(

  title = 'Text',

  tabPanel(

    'Custom App',

    fluidRow(
      radioButtons( 'radio', 'Select Action', choices = list( 'Default' = 'Default', 'Custom' = 'Custom' ),
                    selected = 'Default', inline = T ),
    column( 6, textInput( 'text_given', label = 'Enter Text', value = '' ) ),
      actionButton( 'submit_button', 'Submit' ),
      textOutput( "text")

    )

  )

)

server = function( input, output, session ){

  submitted_text <- eventReactive(input$submit_button,
                {
                  input$text_given
                })

  main = reactive({
    selected_action = input$radio
    if(selected_action == 'Default' ){
      text_to_show = 'Default Text'
    } 
    else
    {
      text_to_show = submitted_text()
    }
    return(text_to_show)
  })

  output$text = renderText( main() )

}

shinyApp( ui = ui, server = server )
```

> EDIT: based on comments

```
library( shiny )
library(shinyjs)

ui = navbarPage(

  title = 'Text',

  tabPanel(

    'Custom App',
    useShinyjs(),
    fluidRow(
      radioButtons( 'radio', 'Select Action', choices = list( 'Default' = 'Default', 'Custom' = 'Custom' ),
                    selected = 'Default', inline = T ),
      column( 6, shinyjs::hidden(textInput( 'text_given', label = 'Enter Text', value = '' ) )),
      shinyjs::hidden(actionButton( 'submit_button', 'Submit' )),
      textOutput( "text")

    )

  )

)

server = function( input, output, session ){

  submitted_text <- eventReactive(input$submit_button,
                                  {
                                    input$text_given
                                  })

  observeEvent(input$radio,
               {
                 if(input$radio=='Default')
                 {
                   hide("text_given")
                   hide("submit_button")
                 }
                 else
                 {
                   show("text_given")
                   show("submit_button")
                 }

               })

  main = reactive({
    selected_action = input$radio
    if(selected_action == 'Default' ){
      text_to_show = 'Default Text'
    } 
    else
    {
      text_to_show = submitted_text()
    }
    return(text_to_show)
  })

  output$text = renderText( main() )

}

shinyApp( ui = ui, server = server )
```

Comment: This works perfectly. Thanks ! Can you kindly help on doing this. I want to hide the text field and submit button when default is selected and want to show it only when custom is selected. How to do this ?

Comment: Thanks a lot ! This works great. Only a small problem is that if I select custom, enter text and submit, go to default and then come back to custom, the previous entered text remains. It would be great if that disappears after submit is clicked. Thanks for helping.

Comment: No problem, you could add updateTextInput("text_given", value="") in the oberveEvent for the radioButtons. Could you please consider upvoting the answer if you found it helpful? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks again. This works as desired. Yes after 15 reputation will.