# Update content of shinydashboardPlus accordion in observeEvent

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shinydashboardplus

I have a shinydashboardPlus `accordion`(AdminLTE2 accordion container) that is collapsed when the application starts ; after having clicked a button, I would like to open the accordion (with `updateAccordion`), show "calculation in progress" inside the accordion, then run the calculation and finally show "calculation done".

My issue is the following : the accordion remains collapsed during the calculation (the first message "computation in progress" does not appear), only the last one is visible at the end.

What is the reason for that ? What is wrong in this minimal example ?

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinydashboardPlus)

shinyApp(
  ui = dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(),
    dashboardSidebar(),
    dashboardBody(
      actionButton("change_acc", "Change Accordion"),
      accordion(
        id = "accordion1",
        accordionItem(
          title = "Accordion 1 Item 1",
          status = "danger",
          collapsed = TRUE,
            uiOutput("accordion_msg")
        )
        )
    ),
    title = "Update Accordion"
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    observeEvent(input$change_acc, {
      updateAccordion(id = "accordion1", selected = 1)
      output$accordion_msg <- renderUI({
        HTML("... calculation in progress ...") ## <<<<<<<<<<<<<<< this message is never printed !
      })
      Sys.sleep(100)
      output$accordion_msg <- renderUI({
        HTML("... calculation done ...")  ### <<<<< but this one is ?!
      })
    })
  }
)
```

EDIT : other trial (also not working) - server without nested renderUI

```
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    x <- reactiveValues()
    x$x <- FALSE
    x$y <- FALSE
    observeEvent(input$change_acc, {
      updateAccordion(id = "accordion1", selected = 1)
      output$accordion_msg <- renderUI({
        HTML("... computation in progress ...") ## <<<<<<<<<<<<<<< this message is never printed !
      })
      x$y <- TRUE
    })
    observeEvent(x$y,{
      if(x$y){
        cat(paste0("start sleep\n"))
        Sys.sleep(5)
        cat(paste0("end sleep\n"))
        x$x <- TRUE
      }
    })
    observeEvent(x$x,{
      if(x$x){
        output$accordion_msg <- renderUI({
          HTML("... computation done ...")
        })
      }
    })
  })
```

Comment: The problem is almost certainly that you nest your two `renderUI`s in an `observeEvent`.  That's never a good idea and, in this case, the second definition of `output$accordion_msg` overwrites the first.  The solution is to (1) unnest your definitions and (2) use an intermediate status variable to update the accordion as you wish.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Nested Reactive Expressions in Shiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45130278/nested-reactive-expressions-in-shiny)

Comment: @Limey Thanks for the comments ; I've tried to unnest the renderUI in the server part (see Edits in the question) ; but still it does not work... Sorry, maybe I misunderstood what you suggested ? any idea of what is going wrong in the 2nd trial ? Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you still had nested reactives, for example, with

```
observeEvent(x$x,{
      if(x$x){
        output$accordion_msg <- renderUI({
          HTML("... computation done ...")
        })
      }
    })
```

and

```
    observeEvent(input$change_acc, {
      updateAccordion(id = "accordion1", selected = 1)
      output$accordion_msg <- renderUI({
        HTML("... computation in progress ...") 
      })
      x$y <- TRUE
    })
```

So, in effect, you have two "competing" definitions of `output$accordion_msg`.

[That's a very hand-wavy explanation and readers who are more technically able than me will be able to give you a more canonical explanation of what's going on.]

Here's a solution that I believe does what you want.  Note that (1) the defintion of no observers/reactives are nested withing the definition of another. **This is a very good rule of thumb when working with Shiny, IMHO.** (2)  The observer that updates `status` is separate to the one that updates `x$msg`.

I first thought `status` should be reactive, but as I was writing the code, I realised that it was easier to make it non-reactive.  To ensure that changes to it are available everywhere it's needed, I use `<<-`.  That's hacky, but simple.  It would probably be better to do something safer in production.

Initially, I had the `observeEvent` update only `status` and the `observe` update only `x$msg`, but that meant that the "in progress" message only appears five seconds after the button click rather than immediately.  (And the "done" message appears ten seconds after the click rather than five.)

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinydashboardPlus)

shinyApp(
  ui = dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(),
    dashboardSidebar(),
    dashboardBody(
      actionButton("change_acc", "Change Accordion"),
      accordion(
        id = "accordion1",
        accordionItem(
          title = "Accordion 1 Item 1",
          status = "danger",
          collapsed = TRUE,
          uiOutput("accordion_msg")
        )
      )
    ),
    title = "Update Accordion"
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    status <- "Ready"
    x <- reactiveValues(msg = "")

    output$accordion_msg <- renderUI({
      HTML(x$msg)
    })
    
    observeEvent(input$change_acc, {
      status <<- "Running"
      x$msg <- "... calculation in progress ..."
      updateAccordion(id = "accordion1", selected = 1)
    })
    
    observe({
      if (status == "Running") {
        x$msg <- "... calculation done ..."
        status <<- "Done"
      }
      invalidateLater(5000)
    })
  }
)
```

Also, note that the `observe` continues to be evaluated every 5 seconds even after the calculation is complete.  You may want to find a way of cancelling or destroying it once it's one it's job.